# Can you do any damage with "rm -R *" on a Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, osx-lion, terminal.app

I just cd to "/" on a Mac and accidentally entered "rm -R *". I know the command means delete everything in "/" but I wasn't sudoing, should I reinstall Mac OS? Or does a mac protect against this sort of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't agree with [Yitzchak's answer](https://superuser.com/a/372722/48078).

If you run `rm -R *`, it will recursively **delete files you own** and have write permissions on. Even if you let the command run for a couple of seconds, it is possible that you deleted some files that you owned. Thus, saying "you're fine" is potentially dangerous. Just check what `ls -R *` lists. This is what you would've removed. The fact that you left out `sudo` will not stop the command from executing.

First, you will delete applications you've installed by dragging them to `/Applications`. They are owned by you. Eventually, the listing will recurse into your home directory under `/Users/`, which by default is owned by your user too, and *not* root. This is where probably all of your private files reside.

I would strongly advise you to **restore from your backup** (you use Time Machine, right?) to a previous point and also check if you miss any important files in your home directory.

If you ran the command without `sudo` or from a non-root shell, you shouldn't have messed with any system files, so reinstalling OS X shouldn't be necessary. That being said, it can't hurt, because a typical OS X (Snow Leopard, Lion) install will not remove your documents, but repair/reinstall system files.

Comment: agreed. Remember, you can delete files where you have write access to the directory, which is more than you think.

Comment: Right you are. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You may have inadvertently removed files to which your user had write permissions to considering you passed the `-R` switch, depending on how long you let the command recurse.

A re-install shouldn't be necessary as @Yitzchak mentioned as your user should not have sufficient permissions to damage critical system files. That being said, if you do experience any odd-behavior or instability, it may behoove you to re-install.